# how to make google map marker clickable? - ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework

i cant make the marker clickable.

this is the code im trying.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LocationHandlerProvider } from '../../providers/location-handler/location-handler';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { ConnectionListernerProvider } from '../../providers/connection-listerner/connection-listerner';


declare var google;
@IonicPage({
  name: 'hospital',
  segment: 'hospital'
})
@Component({
  selector: 'hospital',
  templateUrl: 'hospital.html',
})
export class HospitalPage {

  goLoginPage() {
    this.navCtrl.push('LoginPage');
  }


  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;

  map: any;
  mapInitialised: boolean = false;
  current_location: any;
  apiKey: string = "AIzaSyAM64-qDZZt7UeUC87OirpYF8-TEurvCjs";
  place_view_option: string = "map";
  places: any; //Hold an array of nearby services to the user current direction
  current_location_object: any;
  show_map: boolean = true;
  current_window = null;
  offline_dialog:boolean=false;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public location_handler: LocationHandlerProvider,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public geolocation: Geolocation,
    public connectivityService: ConnectionListernerProvider,
    private ngZOne: NgZone
  ) {
  }
```

I think this code is the problem. can't put too much code so I only put this one. I need this to show the direction if clicked

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', () => {
            this.setSelectedPlace(place_object);
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
            this.setSelectedPlace(place_object);


          });
```

can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

Just do that as below if you need any reference please go to official doc here is link

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Click to zoom'
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    map.setZoom(8);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  });
```